# TSQL - how to determine first and last days of the week for a given week number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in the below format:

```
TrDate:2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Amount: 10.00
TrDate:2018-01-02 00:00:00.000 | Amount: 20.00
```

And I want to consolidate data at weekly level:

```
Week:1 | Start Date: | End Date:| Total Amount
```

I have query which consolidates data at weekly but I do not know how to get the start and end dates for the respective week. This was my query:

```
 SELECT      DATEPART(wk, trdate)     weekno,
     round(SUM(amount),2) AS total_amount
 FROM        <table>
 GROUP BY    DATEPART(wk, trdate);
```

FYI: Week starts from Sunday and Ends on Saturday.

Comment: is the time component of TrDate always going to be midnight, or can it have other values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select weekno, weekStart, weekEnd,   round(SUM(amount),2) AS total_amount from 
(
  SELECT      
    DATEPART(wk, trdate)     weekno,
    DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, trdate)-1), trdate) [WeekStart],
    DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, trdate)), trdate) [WeekEnd],
    amount
  from table1
)t
group by Weekno, weekstart, weekend
```

Comment: Did you try this before posting it?  And @deejay217, did you try this before accepting it?  It doesn't work because of syntax errors:  It's missing a comma after [WeekStart].  After fixing that, it gives another syntax error:   "Column '......trdate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: I'll change downvote to an upvote when the syntax errors are resolved.

Comment: Upvoted.  syntax errors are fixed.  it breaks if any datetime values aren't midnight, but OP's example data wasn't sufficient to give a definitive clue on whether that's possible in his dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression to find the previous Sunday for a given date (it works regardless of `@@DATEFIRST` setting):

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, <date>)
    WHEN 'SUNDAY'    THEN 0
    WHEN 'MONDAY'    THEN 1
    WHEN 'TUESDAY'   THEN 2
    WHEN 'WEDNESDAY' THEN 3
    WHEN 'THURSDAY'  THEN 4
    WHEN 'FRIDAY'    THEN 5
    WHEN 'SATURDAY'  THEN 6
END, <date>) AS weekstart
```

You can use it in your query as follows:

```
SELECT weekno, total_amount, DATEADD(DAY, -CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, refdate)
        WHEN 'SUNDAY'    THEN 0
        WHEN 'MONDAY'    THEN 1
        WHEN 'TUESDAY'   THEN 2
        WHEN 'WEDNESDAY' THEN 3
        WHEN 'THURSDAY'  THEN 4
        WHEN 'FRIDAY'    THEN 5
        WHEN 'SATURDAY'  THEN 6
    END, refdate) AS weekstart, DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, refdate)
        WHEN 'SUNDAY'    THEN 6
        WHEN 'MONDAY'    THEN 5
        WHEN 'TUESDAY'   THEN 4
        WHEN 'WEDNESDAY' THEN 3
        WHEN 'THURSDAY'  THEN 2
        WHEN 'FRIDAY'    THEN 1
        WHEN 'SATURDAY'  THEN 0
    END, refdate) AS weekend
FROM (
    SELECT DATEPART(wk, trdate) weekno
         , ROUND(SUM(amount),2) AS total_amount
         , MIN(trdate) AS refdate
    FROM t
    GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, trdate)
) AS cte
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```
 SELECT 
    weekno,
    convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(dd, 1 - DATEPART(dw, date1), date1),111) startdate,
    convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(dd, 7 - DATEPART(dw, date2), date2),111) enddate,
    total_amount
    from
    (
          SELECT  
            DATEPART(wk, trdate) weekno,
            cast(min(trdate) as date) as date1, 
            cast(max(trdate) as date) as date2, 
            round(SUM(amount),2) AS total_amount
         FROM        <table>
         GROUP BY    DATEPART(wk, trdate)
     ) t
```

produces output like this (note: I added some data of my own to test a couple of edge cases).

[image]

### Notes

1. It wasn't clear in the question whether datetime values can have a time component other than midnight. My answer assumes there might be non-midnight times.
2. The weekno values might seem odd at the beginning and/or end of the year, but the OP's query yields the same value for weekno for those edge cases.
3. Neither OP's query, nor any of the answers so far restrict the data by year, and they group only by week#.  Thus if data from multiple years are included, you will still only get 53 rows, and each row will contain the aggregate data from all years in the data for that week.  The start and end dates will then overlap and look strange.  You could add additional grouping by year to further divide this, but the simplest fix would be to restrict the data to a single year, with a WHERE clause just prior to the GROUP BY clause, e.g.:

   ```
    WHERE trdate >= '2018/01/01' and trdate < '2019/01/01'
   ```